# Why isn't sed working?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, replace

I have a file that has a single line with a lot of `!` characters.  I want to remove all of the `!` characters.

I tried this:

```
sed s/!// myfile
```

and this:

```
sed 's/!//' myfile
```

and this:

```
sed 's/"\!*"//' myfile
```

But they all just print out all of the "!".

I must be missing something obvious.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `g` to your regexp, for global replacement. Otherwise, only the first occurrence will be substituted:

```
sed s/\!//g myfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ sed s/\!//g myfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget poor old `tr`

```
tr -d '!' < filename
```

tr only operates on stdin, so you have to pipe data into it.

Answer (score 2):

add the g at the end in order to replace all occurances.

sed 's/"!*"//g' myfile

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify you want every occurence removed: `sed 's/!//g' myfile`
Note the `g`, which mean 'greedy'.
Without the 'g', you only have the first '!' removed